# When using Simple Fields plugin, how do I pull the information out of the database to display on a page?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, forms

Pretty much what the question says. I used simple fields, but I'm unsure in WP how to get the information back to display on a page?

Comment: can you add a link to that simple forms plugin?

Comment: Do you mean "simple fields" http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-fields/ ?

Comment: yes, sorry that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EAMann helped me and I was able to get the meta data from clicking on "show custom field keys" and using get_post_meta();